# How to decide between goodness of fit tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, goodness-of-fit, aic, bic

I have a question on BIC and AIC.

I have a data set and I need to test this data set if it fits various distributions (for example, Gamma or Poisson, etc.) I need to use AIC and BIC statistics for doing that. 
I found these values:
AIC:  159.7901   BIC:  162.6581.

How can I decide whether this data set fits or not using these calculations?

Comment: I doubt you can do that with AIC or BIC.

Comment: To test if a sample comes from a population I recommend KS test